# Create ScatterPlots using Pandas and matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

i am having trouble creating **scatter plots** using Python/Pandas/Matplotlib.

I want the scatterplot to display how many became doctors,nurses and dentist throughout the years but the problem is that i can only show doctors..

**Data file CSV:** https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mReDAjgZtQk2PkPw8Dr_KuokqnXy2z69

Below is what i have tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    Data = pd.read_csv('D:/Downloads/Datascience/med.csv',dtype={'year': int,'level_1':str, 'value': object})

test = Data[Data['level_1']=='Doctors Per 10,000 Total Population']['year']
print(test)

# {‘col1’ : “float64”, “col2”: “Int64”}

test2 = govtData[govtData['level_1']=='Doctors Per 10,000 Total Population']['value']
print(test2)

print(Data[Data['level_1']=="Doctors Per 10,000 Total Population"])

plt.scatter(test,test2)
plt.xlabel('$Time $ $ Spent$' , fontsize = 12)
plt.ylabel('$Score$' , fontsize = 12)
plt.title ('Scatter Graph')
plt.show()
```

TIA!

Comment: Where can we find the data?  What's the trouble?  code error? format of plot? etc. thx

Comment: please, provide a [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Minimal Reproducible Example, and also say what have you tried and what error/bug your code is raising.

Comment: I have added the data file, I want the scatterplot to display how many became doctors,nurses and dentist throughout the years but the problem is that i can only show doctors..